# rpm not finding files specified

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, specifications

I have a simple spec file:

```
Name:       example
Summary:    example desc
Version:    1
Release:    1
Url:        http://www.example.com
Source:     %{name}-%{version}.tar.bz2
Group:      System Environment/Libraries
BuildRoot:  %{_topdir}/BUILDROOT/%{name}-%{version}

%description
description goes here

%prep
mkdir -p %{buildroot}

%build
pwd

%install
cp -a %{_sourcedir}/%{name}-%{version}/* %{buildroot}

%clean
pwd

%files
/*
```

rpmbuild fails everytime complaining about unpackaged files (all the installed files seem to be not found). No modifications to the %files section seems to produce any difference. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. The sections of the .spec file are evidently influenced by order. Moving the %files section to different places made things work. Parsers: can you learn them rpmbuild developers?

Comment: Where was your %files section that it was causing an issue ? Yes, order matters.  It does in a lot of formats.  Your snide comment is unwarranted.  Accept your own answer and move on.